# show/hide div based on form value

Tags: javascript

```
var test = document.getElementById("TEST1").value;
if (test.value != 1) {
    document.getElementById("field_DOPT").style.display='none';
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. I am getting the TEST1 value as 1 but its not hiding the   div. Any help will be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `test` is the value of the input element `TEST1`, it doesn't have a `value` property

so either assign the element as the value to `test` then use `test.value` in your condition

```
var test = document.getElementById("TEST1");
if (test.value != 1) {
    document.getElementById("field_DOPT").style.display='none';
}
```

or use just test in the condition

```
var test = document.getElementById("TEST1").value;
if (test != 1) {
    document.getElementById("field_DOPT").style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `TEST1` value to the `test` variable, so in test you have do:

```
if (test != 1) {
    document.getElementById("field_DOPT").style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already get the `value` property of your element when you define `test`, and then you look for the `value` property of its `value` property - so the simplest way to improve this code is:

```
var testValue = document.getElementById("TEST1").value;
if (testValue != 1) {
    document.getElementById("field_DOPT").style.display='none';
}
```

I've changed your variable name from `test` to `testValue` so that it's clear that you are not actually dealing with the `TEST1` element but instead with its value (so that it is clear there is no need to get the `value` property.